# Uploaded video from IOS and Android devices can't be merged

Tags: video, ffmpeg

When I try to concatenate one video from IOS and Another from Android user, the output video doesn't work.

I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output
```

Comment: Please [use ffprobe](https://www.bugcodemaster.com/article/use-ffprobe-obtain-information-video-files) to include information about the format of each file in your list, if they aren't the same merging won't work (you'll need to reencode, causing loss). To make Android videos ***similar*** (but possibly still not mergable) go to phone's video settings, "Rear Video Size" and turn on "HEVC" (or turn it off on iPhone). That's probably where the problem lies as the default for each OS is opposite.

Comment: All inputs must have the same formats and parameters. Show info for each input as Rob mentioned if you need help conforming them.